# The reason for not placing an article « un » or « le » before the noun « exploit »

Tags: grammaire, articles

> Son groupe avait réussi à créer cette merveille, grâce à laquelle il est possible de se rendre en un point précis de l'espace-temps, **exploit** qui était jusque-là jugé inconcevable.

I might just as easily phrase it as « **un exploit** qui » or « **l'exploit** qui », so I’m not sure why « **exploit** qui » is the correct phrasing here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On aurait effectivement pu écrire "un exploit qui...", ce qui se fait le plus couramment, mais dans ce cas-ci "l'exploit qui..." serait incorrect car ce n'est pas un exploit connu (l'article défini accompagne un nom dont le sens est entièrement déterminé, or on parle ici d'un exploit parmi d'autre).

L'absence d'article est une figure de style tout à fait admise. Elle permet d'ajouter une emphase sur le mot "exploit", pour montrer à quel point il est grand (comprendre : c'est un exploit parmi d'autres, mais parmi d'autres exploits exceptionnels.) C'est par ailleurs assez courant dans les appositions.

Comment: Dommage que la réponse ne précise pas les règles d'utilisation, s'il y en a de précisément définies.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps Difficile de donner des règles pour les figures de style, leur utilisation étant plutôt liée à la pratique et, dans ce cas, à une exception à la règle. Quant au choix d'un article défini ou non, ce n'était pas la question et d'autres y répondent déjà très bien. J'ai ajouté un peu plus de détail à toute fin utile.

Comment: Même dans cette [liste](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_figures_de_style) ?

Comment: La liste est utile pour classer le type de figure de style (omission morphologique dans ce cas), mais ne donne pas de règle.